# IOC injection of IServerSideEvents

Tags: c#, unit-testing, servicestack, xunit

I am writing unit tests for my IOC. 
One of my interfaces injects IServerEvents.

I am including events via:

```
  ServerEventsFeature serverEventsFeature = new ServerEventsFeature()
            {
                LimitToAuthenticatedUsers = false,
                NotifyChannelOfSubscriptions = false,
                OnConnect = (eventSubscription, dictionary) =>
                {
                },
                OnSubscribe = (eventSubscription) =>
                {
                }
            };
```

However, container.Resolve gives the following error when debugging (Not through unit tests) :

```
'container.Resolve<IServerEvents>()' threw an exception of type 'System.Exception'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233088
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: {System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'ServiceStack.IServerEvents' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Funq.Container.ResolveImpl[TService](String name, Boolean throwIfMissing)}
    Message: "Error trying to resolve Service 'ServiceStack.IServerEvents' or one of its autowired dependencies (see inner exception for details)."
    Source: "ServiceStack"
    StackTrace: "   at Funq.Container.ResolveImpl[TService](String name, Boolean throwIfMissing)"
    TargetSite: {TService ResolveImpl[TService](System.String, Boolean)}
```

This does work in normal usage, but manual Resolve of the interface does not work.

What I am wondering is :

A) proper way to unit test this integration of server events

B) Should I merely mock the IServerEvents on the container with a RegisterAs<>() in unit tests

C) Why the injection works fine but container.Resolve() fails.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ServerEventsFeature` in a unit test, you'll only be able to make use of it in an [integration test](https://docs.servicestack.net/testing#integration-testing). You can find some working examples in [ServerEventTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/ServerEventTests.cs).

As `ServerEventsFeature` is a plugin, it needs to be registered as a plugin to function:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature { ... });
```

Which when the plugin is registered will [register the `MemoryServerEvents` dependency](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/62403cf85c4c15b862c2448bac4892bc0a3c8c4c/src/ServiceStack/ServerEventsFeature.cs#L82):

```
container.Register<IServerEvents>(memoryServerEvents);
```